# Dropdown menu clickable area adjust

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a dropdown menu with bigger clickable area. Anytime I click within the the drop menu but outside the checkbox the menu closes. How can I change the bootstrap code to adjust this? I couldn't find locate the line to adjust this.

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="btn-group dropright">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      Dropright
    </button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu">
          <!-- Dropdown menu links -->
          <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox1" value="option1">
            <label class="form-checka-label" for="inlineCheckbox1">1</label>
          </div>
          <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox2" value="option2">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox2">2</label>
          </div>
          <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox3" value="option3" disabled>
            <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox3">3 (disabled)</label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="container"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding some extra padding to your .form-check-label and .form-check-input, those should both be clickable.

Answer (score 0):

I have added width level 100 to .btn-group and .dropdown-menu classes in order to achieve this. It was not working for other classes. And again in the labels, I have added some styling in order to display how the border works.

To prevent closing the dropdown on a click, I have included a script to stop 
  **stop Propagation**

```js
$('.dropdown-menu').click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

```css
.btn-group,
.dropdown-menu {
  width: 100%;
}

label {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0 0 10px;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

label:hover {
  background: #eee;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="btn-group dropright">
      <button type="button btn-class" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle btn-block" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      Dropright
    </button>
      <div class="dropdown-menu">
        <!-- Dropdown menu links -->
        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
          <label class="form-checka-label" for="inlineCheckbox1"><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox1" value="option1">
         1</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox2"><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox2" value="option2">
        2</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox3"><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox3" value="option3" disabled>
          3 (disabled)</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="container"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```